# bazel - netty_tcnative errors

Tags: java, netty, grpc, bazel, grpc-java

I'm trying to run a java application powered by grpc but I need netty_tcnative to work. I'm following an example https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/example-tls/BUILD.bazel. So far, I haven't been successful to make it work. I get errors like this:

```
INFO: Transport failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opencensus/contrib/grpc/metrics/RpcMeasureConstants
        at io.grpc.internal.DeprecatedCensusConstants.<clinit>(DeprecatedCensusConstants.java:30)
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$ServerTracerFactory.newServerStreamTracer(CensusStatsModule.java:674)
        at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.newServerContext(StatsTraceContext.java:80)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:425)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:101)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:801)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:373)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:321)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:660)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onHeadersRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:56)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$2.processFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:483)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readHeadersFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:491)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:254)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:174)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:378)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:242)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:794)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:424)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opencensus.contrib.grpc.metrics.RpcMeasureConstants
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 36 more

Mar 19, 2020 2:17:32 PM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
INFO: Transport failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.internal.DeprecatedCensusConstants
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$ServerTracerFactory.newServerStreamTracer(CensusStatsModule.java:674)
        at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.newServerContext(StatsTraceContext.java:80)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:425)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:101)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:801)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:373)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:321)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onHeadersRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:660)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onHeadersRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:56)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$2.processFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:483)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readHeadersFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:491)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:254)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:174)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:378)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:242)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:794)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:424)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My BUILD file looks like that:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
load("@io_grpc_grpc_java//:java_grpc_library.bzl", "java_grpc_library")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//java:image.bzl", "java_image")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_bundle", "container_image", "container_push")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//contrib:push-all.bzl", "docker_push")

proto_library(
    name = "account_proto",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/proto/account.proto"]),
    deps = ["@googleapi//google/api:annotations_proto"],
)

java_proto_library(
    name = "account_proto_java",
    deps = [":account_proto"],
)

java_grpc_library(
    name = "account_java_grpc",
    srcs = [":account_proto"],
    deps = [":account_proto_java"],
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "cred_tar",
    srcs = glob(["config/revoked-microservices-service_key.json"]),
    package_dir = "src/main/app",
)

java_image(
    name = "account_service",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    runtime_deps = [
        "@maven//:io_netty_netty_tcnative_boringssl_static",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_google_cloud_pubsub",
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_google_cloud_storage",
        "@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_netty_shaded",
        "@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_protobuf",
        "@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_stub",
        "@maven//:mysql_mysql_connector_java",
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_sql_mysql_socket_factory_connector_j_8",
        "@maven//:com_zaxxer_HikariCP",
        "@maven//:com_google_inject_guice",
        "@maven//:jaxen_jaxen",
        "@maven//:org_dom4j_dom4j",
        "@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_simple",
        "@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_api",
        "@maven//:log4j_log4j",
        "@maven//:com_google_code_gson_gson",
        "@maven//:junit_junit",
        "@maven//:com_sun_xml_ws_jaxws_rt",
        "@maven//:javax_xml_ws_jaxws_api",
        "@maven//:com_google_guava_guava",
        "@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_api",
        "@maven//:com_google_protobuf_protobuf_java",
        "@maven//:com_google_protobuf_protobuf_java_util",
        "@maven//:com_google_api_grpc_proto_google_common_protos",
        "@io_grpc_grpc_java//api",
        "@io_grpc_grpc_java//protobuf",
        "@io_grpc_grpc_java//stub",
        "@io_grpc_grpc_java//netty",
        "@maven//:io_netty_netty_handler",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_java",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_java_util",
        ":account_proto_java",
        ":account_java_grpc",
    ],
    main_class = "com.revoked.account.Application",
)

container_image(
    name = "account_service_image",
    base = ":account_service",
    tars = [":cred_tar"],
    ports = ["8080"],
    workdir = "/usr/main/app",
    env = {
        "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8",
        "TZ": "America/New_York",  
    },
)

container_bundle(
    name = "bundle_image",
    images = {
        "revoked/account-microservice:bazel-test-1.0.2": ":account_service_image",
    }
)

container_push(
    name = "push_image",
    image = ":account_service_image",
    format = "Docker",
    registry = "index.docker.io",
    repository = "revoked/account-microservice",
    tag = "bazel-test-1.0.2",
)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great!

Comment: i am not sure it is a cause or not, but you should not use `grpc-netty` and `grpc-netty-shaded` together. can you remove one and try?

Comment: Hi @creamsoup, you're correct. I kept `grpc-netty-shaded`. The problem was that I didn't have `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.opencensus/opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics/0.8.0` funny enough it's in my `maven_install.json` file. I need to look into the override targets configuration that I can use in maven.

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java's grpc-netty-shaded target does not actually shade, so it appears your `@maven//:io_grpc_*` targets are actually pulling from Maven Central. You should be using the grpc-java repository targets instead.

In order to have the Maven dependencies and Bazel dependencies mix appropriately, use `maven_install`'s `override_targets` within your WORKSPACE [as done in the example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/1bf5ad15272dd53e55bc37863ecaa1e3eb424bfa/examples/WORKSPACE#L34).

```py
maven_install(
    artifacts = IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_ARTIFACTS,
    generate_compat_repositories = True,
    override_targets = IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_OVERRIDE_TARGETS,
    repositories = [
        "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
    ],
)
```